# Where to put an adjective to avoid ambiguity?

Tags: adjectives, ambiguity

The essence of this question is not about style. It is foremost about avoiding ambiguity.

The sentence is "She called me." If I want to use the word "sniffling" to describe the caller, where should I put it? I don't want to use the adverb "snifflingly".

If a noun is used instead of the pronoun 'She', it's very clear to say "a sniffling child called me".

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/601225/2085).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say:

> She called me, sniffling.

That would be an example of an *[absolute adjective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective#Form)*:

> *Absolute* adjectives do not belong to a larger construction (aside from a larger adjective phrase), and typically modify either the subject of a sentence or whatever noun or pronoun they are closest to; for example, *happy* is an absolute adjective in "The boy, happy with his lollipop, did not look where he was going."

Comment: Is it OK to say "She, sniffling, called me"? How about "She sniffling called me"?

Comment: The first doesn't break rules, but it's not natural for such a short and simple sentence to have two commas.  The second does break rules, and shouldn't be used.  In case you were wondering, *she called me, sniffling* is just fine - no native speaker will think that it was me sniffling.

Answer (score 2):

If you must use the word "She", I would put the adjective at the end of the sentence:

> She called me, sniffling.

*Note that without proper punctuation this may be ambiguously interpreted, with an alternate interpretation suggesting that "sniffling" were a name:*

> *She called me "sniffling".*